# Where can I find my serialized Sitecore items?

Tags: content-editor, serialization

I serialized a few Sitecore items to keep them on my version control system using the following menu:

[image]

And now I must find them to finish my task.

**Where exactly are those files?**

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The previous answer is correct for default configuration on Sitecore 8 or 9.

The serialization folder path can be set using next setting .

```
<!--  SERIALIZATION FOLDER
            Points to the root of serialized databases tree (when using serialization functionality).
            Default value: $(dataFolder)/serialization
      -->
    <setting name="SerializationFolder" value="$(dataFolder)/serialization" />
```

Above setting is part of the Sitecore.config and is relative to **dataFolder**.

If you want to change the **SerializationFolder** I recommend you to path this setting using patch config. 
 **dataFolder** setting is defined like a sitecore variable:

```
<sc.variable name="dataFolder" value="/App_Data" />
```

Answer (score 2):

It depends on which major version you are using.

If you are using **Sitecore 8.x or lower**:

- C:\inetpub\wwwroot\Instance_Name\Data\serialization

If you are using **Sitecore 9.x or higher**:

- C:\inetpub\wwwroot\Instance_Name\App_Data\serialization

Comment: To clarify; downvoted because this has nothing whatsoever to do with Sitecore version. It's just the defaults that changed from 8 to 9. As they also did from 5 to 6.